# Element Tree Syntax Error (not well-formed with invalid token)

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, python-2.x, elementtree

I am trying to use the Element Tree modules but I end up to some Error which I can't understand.

My code here is based on the Python documentation itself, [Python Element Tree doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) ,somehow it gave me an error when trying to run the script;

```
try:
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
file_name_xml = "curl-result.xml"
tree = ET.parse(file_name_xml)
tree.getroot()
```

When I run this code:

```
./python2.6 modify_xml_file.py
```

Then, it gave me this error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "modify_xml_file.py", line 8, in <module>
    tree = ET.parse(file_name_xml)
  File "<string>", line 45, in parse
  File "<string>", line 32, in parse
SyntaxError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of `cElementTree` included in Python 2.6 throws a `SyntaxError` exception for *malformed XML*:

```
>>> with open('bad.xml', 'w') as badxml:
...     badxml = '<foobar\n'
...
>>> import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
>>> tree = ET.parse('bad.xml')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 45, in parse
  File "<string>", line 32, in parse
SyntaxError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

This is a bug in the C acceleration code fixed in Python 2.7. The (slower) Python parser throws a more helpful error:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> tree = ET.parse('bad.xml')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 862, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 587, in parse
    self._root = parser.close()
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1254, in close
    self._parser.Parse("", 1) # end of data
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

Fix your XML input file.

What changed in 2.7 is that ElementTree was [updated to version 1.3](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.7.html#updated-module-elementtree-1-3), a version that [improved the parser](http://effbot.org/zone/elementtree-13-intro.htm#parser-improvements), introducing a new `ParseError` exception, which is a subclass of `SyntaxError`.

Comment: After removing additional data of the curl result on the top of my xml, I managed to run the code. Thank you, but of course, I was very sure the code is not malformed before because I tried to read it online using http://xmlgrid.net/ . Anyway, thank you. I don't know why this question should get downvoted though. I tried to ask a question which I have done some research before, maybe my fault for asking inappropriate question. Thank you again. :)

Comment: @yunaranyancat: try to make your question as complete as possible; including your XML (and how you produced it) would have made it much easier for people to answer, because we can then verify the issue. This is called a [MCVE]. Creating a proper MCVE (where you test the steps to see if the problem is indeed still there) can often already lead to a solution.

Comment: Noted with thanks, will use this guide in the future.

Comment: @yunaranyancat: I'm not saying that that is why it was downvoted (we can't read the minds, yet, unfortunately), but that *could* be a reason.

Comment: It's okay, at least you gave me the good ideas so I can relate and improve with my way of asking questions..